# cross platform perl interface to init/rc.d scripts?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script to install a web-application which needs to turn on mysql and apache if they are not already on and have those services start at boot if they are not already configured to do so.  Later on, I'd like to check that the service is running before attempting to interact with it.

Right now my script branches on the os: are you Fedora? are you a Red Hat relative which is not Fedora? Are you Debian?...etc.  That's so I know whether to use `systemctl`, `service`, or `chkconfig`.

Is there a better way to handle this?  I was hoping for a module on cpan similar in cross-platform drudgery handling spirit as the best of perl's standard modules, but I haven't come across one.  So right now adding support for a new OS means tracking down how it handles such services and watching for changes in this as new versions of currently supported os's come out.

Any suggestions for better ways to handle this or recommended approaches?